i am trying to run app with firebase but I am facing this problem

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.


Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 21 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [:firebase_auth] E:\flutter_projects\flutter_application_1\build\firebase_auth\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 21
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 21,
or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 23,
or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

what should i do
and tried to add this code but also not working
android {
defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion 23
}
}

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In android/app/build.gradle, replace
minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion

with
minSdk = 23

